# SQL Trigger that creates new table when a new record is added to current table

Tags: mysql, ms-access, mysql-workbench, table

It's been quite a few years since I have done DB work.  I am working through mysql workbench (using MS Access as a frontend).

I have a base table that I am multilinking (basically a name index type of thing). Through a form, the table is updated (a record added) and I want that new record to trigger an event that creates a table and that table is named based on what the user inputted in the form/record.

Any thoughts on how to do this?  Good tutorial/documentation that you would recommend reading?
Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I have a habit of just saying either mysql or workbench - figured I would say workbench so that you had an understanding of the interface I am using.

Each new table will be customized based on x months - in which data is put in for each month for anywhere from 30 to 500 records.  

Sometimes it will be as little as 6 months and other times it will be as large as 48months.  Instead of creating a table that will have to grow to encompass 48 months and try to force everything to play nice, I am thinking that its better all around to seperate tables (perf, organizationally, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first

this would you use, to create special table per id Name and table you have to add

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER after_table_insert
AFTER INSERT
ON tabl1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET @sql = CONCAR("CREATE TABLE table_",NEW.name,"_",NEW.ID, " (id INT,name TEXT)");
    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

If you had a table for all

```
CREATE TABLE Table1_companion
( id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEy
, Refid  INTEGER
,col1 TEXT
,col2 TEXT
,FOREIGN KEY (Refid) REFERENCES tavle1(id));
```

So you have

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.* FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table1_companion t2 ON t1.id = t2.Refid;
```

And when you have a n:m Relationship

You need two tables

```
CREATE TABLE Table1_companion
( tc_id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEy
,col1 TEXT
,col2 TEXT);

CREATE TABLE Table1_relation
(
, Ref_id  INTEGER
, Ref_tc_id   BIGINT
,FOREIGN KEY (Ref_id) REFERENCES table1(id)
,FOREIGN KEY (Ref_tc_id) REFERENCES Table1_companion(tc_id ));
```

Of course you need two joins for that.

You could take a look at normalization.

With that you have a relational database, that works with every rdms.

this is of course only a basic idea,  you must have your own datatypes and foreign keys need of both sides the same datatype, and always remember have every information only once in  your database